# Making attoparsec parsers recursive

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I've been coding up an attoparsec parser and have been hitting a pattern where I want to turn parsers into recursive parsers (recursively combining them with the monad bind >>= operator).

So I created a function to turn a parser into a recursive parser as follows:

```
recursiveParser :: (a -> A.Parser a) -> a -> A.Parser a
recursiveParser parser a = (parser a >>= recursiveParser parser) <|> return a
```

Which is useful if you have a recursive data type like

```
data Expression = ConsExpr Expression Expression | EmptyExpr

parseRHS :: Expression -> Parser Expression
parseRHS e = ConsExpr e <$> parseFoo

parseExpression :: Parser Expression
parseExpression = parseLHS >>= recursiveParser parseRHS
  where parseLHS = parseRHS EmptyExpr
```

Is there a more idiomatic solution? It almost seems like `recursiveParser` should be some kind of fold...  I also saw `sepBy` in the docs, but this method seems to suit me better for my application.

**EDIT:** Oh, actually now that I think about it should actually be something similar to `fix`... Don't know how I forgot about that.

**EDIT2:** Rotsor makes a good point with his alternative for my example, but I'm afraid my AST is actually a bit more complicated than that. It actually looks something more like this (although this is still simplified)

```
data Segment = Choice1 Expression
             | Choice2 Expression
data Expression = ConsExpr Segment Expression 
                | Token String
                | EmptyExpr
```

where the string `a -> b` brackets to the right and `c:d` brackets to the left, with `:` binding more tightly than `->`.

I.e. `a -> b` evaluates to

```
(ConsExpr (Choice1 (Token "a")) (Token "b"))
```

and `c:d` evaluates to

```
(ConsExpr (Choice2 (Token "d")) (Token "c"))
```

I suppose I could use `foldl` for the one and `foldr` for the other but there's still more complexity in there. Note that it's recursive in a slightly strange way, so `"a:b:c -> e:f -> :g:h ->"` is actually a valid string, but `"-> a"` and `"b:"` are not. In the end `fix` seemed simpler to me. I've renamed the recursive method like so:

```
fixParser :: (a -> A.Parser a) -> a -> A.Parser a
fixParser parser a = (parser a >>= fixParser parser) <|> pure a
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious - Is there a benefit of using Attoparsec rather than Stream ByteString m Char from Parsec 3?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with haskell parsing libraries to be honest, however Attoparsec seemed extremely lightweight and performant (http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2010/03/03/whats-in-a-parser-attoparsec-rewired-2/) which is what I wanted for this application. Also I'm not too concerned about decent error messages which I see as Parsec's main benefit. However, if I had to parse something challenging like C, I'd definitely go with Parsec.

Comment: Interesting benchmark. I didn't realize that the performance boosts from attoparsec didn't come solely from the use of ByteString - which is what I assumed because I thought that it was created during the era as Parsec 2.

Comment: @monadic yes, it looks like Bryan O’Sullivan has really done an incredible job fine tuning this

Answer (score 4):

Why not just parse a list and fold it into whatever you want later?
Maybe I am missing something, but this looks more natural to me:

```
consChain :: [Expression] -> Expression
consChain = foldl ConsExpr EmptyExpr

parseExpression :: Parser Expression
parseExpression = consChain <$> many1 parseFoo
```

And it's shorter too.

As you can see, `consChain` is now independent from parsing and can be useful somewhere else. Also, if you separate out the result folding, the somewhat unintuitive recursive parsing simplifies down to `many` or `many1` in this case.

You may want to take a look at how `many` is implemented too:

```
many :: (Alternative f) => f a -> f [a]
many v = many_v
    where many_v = some_v <|> pure []
          some_v = (:) <$> v <*> many_v
```

It has a lot in common with your `recursiveParser`:

- `some_v` is similar to `parser a >>= recursiveParser parser`
- `many_v` is similar to `recursiveParser parser`

You may ask why I called your recursive parser function unintuitive. This is because this pattern allows parser argument to affect the parsing behaviour (`a -> A.Parser a`, remember?), which may be useful, but not obviously (I don't see a use case for this yet). The fact that your example does not use this feature makes it look redundant.

Comment: Seconding this answer - parse a list, then use a smart constructor to fold it into a summary value is the idiomatic solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer for my question. I think the reason why many doesn't work for me is that my AST actually involves a choice, it's not as simple as the one I gave in my question. It's a good answer though

Comment: @Rehno, could you please expand your question with an additional use case, where the functionality of `recursiveParser` is fully used? I'm curious. Also, I'd be happy to try and improve my answer then!